# Repetition of input, with while and arrays

Tags: arrays, character, multiple-instances, repeat

I'm trying to do a code in which he requests the length of the word(n, n <= 100000) and then the word itself, until the n equals zero and ends the processing; the output requests all of the words being reversed.

```
Entrance         Output  

     7           odacova        
   avocado        esuoh
     5
   house
     0
```

Here's the code that I was trying to do:

```
numeros = []
word = []
for i in numeros:
   while i <= 100000:
      n = int(input())  #always ask the length and the word
      s = str(input())
      numeros.append(n)
      word.append(s)
      if i == 0:
         for w in word:
            print(w[::-1])   #output with the words reversed
            break
```

Comment: so what's your issue?

Comment: the code doesn't run anything at all, I don't know how to think another way for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's cause your array `numeros` is empty to begin with, so your for loop would not even run. I'm also relying heavily on your description of what you want, since your code is quite different from your description. Here's something that should work:

```
numeros = []
words = []

while True:
    n = int(input())    # get number of characters input
    if n == 0:    # if input is 0, print all reversed words and exit the program
        for w in words:
            print(w[::-1])   #output with the words reversed
        break
    if n <= 100000:
        s = str(input())    # get word input
        numeros.append(n)
        words.append(s)
```

Comment: Wow! thanks, I didn't remember how to use the 'while true' statement, much obliged